# R: subset multiple data frames at once in for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, subset

I have a large series of data frames in R on which I want to perform some actions all at once in a for loop.

The data frames contain information on gene expression data. For each gene, there is information on upregulation/downregulation and an associated P-value. Ultimately, I want to obtain a new data frame containing the number of significantly (P value < 0.05) up- and downregulated genes for each data frame.

I am going about this in two steps:

1. subset the data frames in subsets containing only up- and downregulated genes
2. calculate the number of significant genes in each subsetted data frame

First, let's make two dummy data frames:

```
#data frame 1
gene = c('gene1','gene2','gene3','gene4','gene5','gene6')
direction = c('up','up','down','down','down','up')
Pvalue = as.numeric(c(0.05,0.06,0.001,0.075,0.11,0.12))
df1 = as.data.frame(cbind(gene,direction,Pvalue))
```

> ```
> > df1 
>    gene direction Pvalue
> 1 gene1        up   0.05
> 2 gene2        up   0.06
> 3 gene3      down  0.001
> 4 gene4      down  0.075
> 5 gene5      down   0.11
> 6 gene6        up   0.12
> ```

```
#data frame 2
gene = c('gene1','gene2','gene3','gene4','gene5','gene6')
direction = c('down','up','down','down','up','up')
Pvalue = as.numeric(c(0.043,0.001,0.34,0.96,0.001,0.04))
df2 = as.data.frame(cbind(gene,direction,Pvalue))
```

> ```
> > df2
>    gene direction Pvalue
> 1 gene1      down  0.043
> 2 gene2        up  0.001
> 3 gene3      down   0.34
> 4 gene4      down   0.96
> 5 gene5        up  0.001
> 6 gene6        up   0.04
> ```

Then, I made a list containing the names of all data frames:

```
df_summary = c('df1','df2')
```

After which I use a for loop over this list to do steps 1 and 2 outlined above:

```
df3 = data.frame()
for (df in df_summary){
  df_down = df[df$direction == 'down',]
  df_up = df[df$direction == 'up',]
  df_down_sign = length(which(df_down$Pvalue < 0.05))
  df_up_sign = length(which(df_up$Pvalue < 0.05))
  df3 = rbind.data.frame(df3, c(df_down_sign,df_up_sign))
}
```

This code works perfectly fine on individual data frames outside the loop, but throws me the following error when I run the loop:

> `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

The output I am looking for should look like this:

> ```
>   dataframe number
> 1       df1      1
> 2       df1      0
> 3       df2      1
> 4       df2      3
> ```

So my question: why am I getting this error in the for loop, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that after posting my question I came across something that looks like a solution.

Simply running

```
df_summary = list(df1,df2)
```

instead of

```
df_summary = c('df1','df2')
```

seems to solve my problem!

Comment: I found this answer here [Running for loop for multiple dataframes in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62240627/running-for-loop-for-multiple-dataframes-in-r?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

The following solves the problem.

```
df_list <- mget(ls(pattern = "^df"))

df3 <- lapply(seq_along(df_list), function(i){
  dftmp <- df_list[[i]]
  dfname <- names(df_list)[i]
  agg <- aggregate(Pvalue ~ direction, dftmp, function(x) sum(x < 0.05))
  cbind.data.frame(dataframe = dfname, agg)
})
df3 <- do.call(rbind, df3)

df3
#  dataframe direction Pvalue
#1       df1      down      1
#2       df1        up      0
#3       df2      down      1
#4       df2        up      3
```